# How to hold a button and record a sound?

Tags: java, android, record

I'm a new android developer.

I want to record a sound via press and hold of a button, and on release of the button, audio should be saved in external storage.

I know how to record an audio file.

please help me.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? This is a pretty broad question, in its current state you aren't likely to get much help. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AndrewBrooke i write a code that record a sound by press "Record" and when press "stop" recording is stopped and save in SDcard
i want to record by a button,when hold "record" its start to recording and when drop(unhold?) button recordig finish and save in sdcard

Comment: Ah, if that code works for you, look at @Rahul Tiwari's answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separate Back Stack for each tab in Android using Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987334/separate-back-stack-for-each-tab-in-android-using-fragments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

1. implement onTouchListener for your button
2. start recording at on action down event
3. stop recording and save to file on action up event.

example:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            // start recording.
            return true;
        }
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            // Stop recording and save file
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

also refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32858800/1529129) for a similar behaviour.